# How to with update my database in android

Tags: android, sql-update

I have an unresolved issue with my database. The user registers with a username and a password and from an EditProfile class he can change both of them. The problem is that although its seems to work it doesn't update either. This is my code.

```
btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (db.getUser(1).getUsername().equals(edtOldUsername.getText().toString())) {  
                if (db.getUser(1).getPassword().equals(edtOldPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    if(edtNewPassword.getText().toString().equals(edtConfirmNewPassword.getText().toString()))
                    {
                        db.updateUser(new User(edtNewUsername.getText().toString(), edtNewPassword.getText().toString(), ""));
                        finish();
                    }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Password! Try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username! Try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           

        }
    });
```

and this is my dbhelper code

```
public int updateUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME,user.getUsername());
    values.put(KEY_PASS, user.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_BDATE, user.getBdate());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_USER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getID()) });
}
```

No respond required... Problem solved. Thnx anyway...:)

Comment: You seem to miss the id of the user, at least I can't see where you set it. If you will only have one user in your database, you might think about removing the where clause `KEY_ID + " = ?"` completely

Comment: @WarrenFaith the line below his update statement are his paremeters, where he sets the `KEY_ID` ... `new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getID()) }`

Comment: @Doomsknight He just passing a User object which he creates without providing an ID, so the questions remains: Where does this ID come from? Exactly, nobody knows so I guess: The ID does not match with the record he wants to update.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Ah yea. Your probably right. Need to see what his User Constructor is doing. Im guessing where has made the mistake is that he is constructing a new user, rather than settings the new password/username of the current user and passing that to his update method

Comment: You are all correct. I forgot to update my dbhelper code. Rookie mistake...

Comment: Adding "No respond required... Problem solved." doesn't really help future visitors. Please either post an answer describing how you fixed the problem or consider deleting the question.